# Using a second camera in the background to record gameplay

Tags: unity

Using the Unity recorder in the Editor I can add a second camera to the scene and have it do something cool like rotate around a pivot, only rendering gameplay and record that.

While I play as normal with primary camera and can see UI, move around etc.

Is there any way I can do this type of recording in a build? Where I record a view that doesnt record what the primary camera sees, but only what this secondary recording camera sees?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with that "recording"?

Comment: @Philipp use it for trailer, and game runs much smoother in build :)

Comment: That probably won't help. Do you know why the game runs slower in the editor? Because you are rendering it twice, once in the scene view and once in the game view. When you have a second camera during the build recording to a render texture, then you are going to experience the same performance penalty. If you want to make a trailer with a better framerate than your machine can handle, then why not use [Time.timeScale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) to make it run slower and then speed up the footage?

Comment: @Philipp Yeah I know, but my publisher want to be able to record in a build. So just wanted to check if anyone knew how. Worst case I give them access to my project and they can do it in editor.